# Maximum height for selected expansion-panel with Flex-Layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, height, panel, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular Material [expansion-panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) with Flex-Layout and I would like that when one panel is "expanded", it takes all the maximum height thanks to "fxFlex".

DEMO:

[image]

I tried to put "fxFlex" in my two expansion-panel, but that does not correspond to my request.
The "fxFlex" should be positioned on the expansion-panel which is "expanded".

Unfortunately, I do not find any solution to my problem.

Here is the [Stacklitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html) and the DEMO of the result.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-etb4yk?file=styles.css)

Comment: your `mat-expansion-panel` over ride with flex if you have to unset flex in your `mat-expansion-panel`class then your problem is temporary solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers I found a possible solution, [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-4-component).

But the animation is not fluid and the panel is cut.
If you have other solutions, I'm interested.